# SQL Format Time Object From 24 Hour to 12

Tags: sql, time, format

Is there a way to convert a time object to a 12 hour format in SQL? I can't nessessarilly use datetime because the data being retrieved is not specific for dates.

16:45:00 --> 4:45 PM

Comment: In where? Oracle? SQLServer? MySql? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
DECLARE @aux NVARCHAR(8)='16:45:00'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CAST(@aux AS TIME),100)
```