# Specific time/hour format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I've seen many questions related to the format and `date/time` conversion in SQL Server but none answer my concern (it is not duplicated). [For example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745958/sql-format-time-object-from-24-hour-to-12)

When executing this statement:

```
select 
    convert(varchar(20), cast('2018/03/05 18:00:00.000' as time), 100) as entryTime
```

I get this result:

[image]

I want the output to be `06:00:00 p.m.`

Is there any way to get a result like this: `06:00:00 p.m.`?

**Environment:** SQL Server 2008 R2

Unfortunately, the `FORMAT` and `FORMATDATETIME` functions are not yet available in this SQL Server version.

Comment: what's the real benefit in formatting through sql? best to do this over the application. in SQL a date is a date a time is a time, comparing of these variables will need casting.

Comment: I think this is something you should address in the presentation layer. It's technically possible to get something like this in sql (e.g. using style 22 instead of 100, using a ltrim + right('0' + ..., 12) trick to insert a 0 at the beginning, etc) but you should really just keep the date/time formats as is in SQL.

Comment: I need to get just that format for something I'm doing, that format as is with the lowercase letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `right`, string concatenation and `replace` I managed to avoid using the value more than once for the appropriate result:

```
SELECT  REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                RIGHT(
                    '0000000000' + 
                        CONVERT(
                        varchar(10), 
                        cast('2018/03/05 18:00:00.000' as time(0)), 
                        109),
                10), 
            'PM', 
            ' p.m.'),
        'AM',
        ' a.m.') as entryTime
```

Result:

```
entryTime
06:00:00 p.m.
```

Comment: no question this can be done in sql but two wrongs do not make it right.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I totally agree it should be done in the presentation layer. However, sometimes you don't have control over the presentation layer....

Answer (score 1):

*I haven't tested this, as I'm on my phone, but perhaps*. Now tested and corrected:

```
STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(26),GETDATE(),109),14),9,4,' ')
```

Comment: It does not work, with this you get as a result: ` 6:20:21 7P`

Comment: Try: SELECT STUFF(RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(40),CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018/03/05 18:00:00.000'),109),14)),14),9,4,' ')

Comment: As I said, I'm on the phone, so I couldn't test (sorry), however, you should also be able to make simple changes like fixing a slight numbering error. ;) Also, oddly, edit is missing below my post, so I can't fix it...

Comment: I was telling the OP to try that, I took your code and debugged it but it wouldn't have felt right posting a new answer and taking all the credit so I edited your answer so you would get the credit, but now it's waiting for peer review so I put it in the comments as well.  Then I upvoted your answer for doing this on your phone!  :)

Comment: I've fixed it now. @MJH, no need for the `LTRIM`,or double `CONVERT`, it simply needed to be changed from a `varchar(25)` to `varchar(26)` and to `9,4` from `10,3`.

Comment: The LTRIM was for the leading zero on times between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), CAST('2018/03/05 18:00:00.000' as  DATETIME), 109), 12, 8) 
       + ' ' + 
       LOWER(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), CAST('2018/03/05 18:00:00.000'  as DATETIME), 109), 25, 1))
       + '.' + 
       LOWER(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), CAST('2018/03/05 18:00:00.000' as DATETIME), 109), 26, 1))
       + '.'
```

Updated more complete solution as for the leading zero need more info if you are using variable to test if it's greater than 10